# How to "extract" string before "-" but if the string itself can contain a "-"?

Tags: regex

I have list of packages like this (it's bigger than this):

```
accounts-qml-module-0.7-3
accountsservice-0.6.55-3
alsa-firmware-1.2.1-2
alsa-oss-1.1.8-3
alsa-plugins-1:1.2.2-2
alsa-utils-1.2.3-2
augeas-1.12.0-2
baloo-5.74.0-1
baloo-widgets-20.08.1-1
binutils-2.35-2
breath2-icon-themes-1.0.10-2
breath2-wallpaper-1.0.10-2
bridge-utils-1.7-1
brltty-6.0-11
cfitsio-1:3.49-1
clucene-2.3.3.4-11
colord-sane-1.4.4+9+g1ce26da-2
confuse-3.3-1
containerd-1.4.1-1
convertlit-1.8-10
cpio-2.13-2
cracklib-2.9.7-2
cronie-1.5.5-1
cups-2.3.3-3
cups-filters-1.28.3-1
cups-pdf-3.0.1-5
cups-pk-helper-0.2.6-4
debootstrap-1.0.123-1
dhcpcd-9.2.0-1
diffutils-3.7-3
ding-libs-0.6.1-3
discount-2.2.7-1
djvulibre-3.5.27-6
dkms-2.8.3-1.1
docbook-xml-4.5-9
docbook-xsl-1.79.2-7
```

I'd like to have:

```
accounts-qml-module
accountsservice
alsa-firmware
alsa-oss
alsa-plugins
alsa-utils
augeas
baloo
baloo-widgets
```

but I don't really know how to do since there are some packets that have a "-" dash inside and I'm very confused about how could I achieve this avoiding to do it manually...

Is there a bash "trick" to do it?

Comment: would it be fair to say you want to trim any number of trailing `(-[0-9.]+)*`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex :

```
^.+?(?=-[\d.\-:+]+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/FZ5TE9/2)